# Make a website for running code

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, css

I'm currently developing a programming contest website, and want to implement support for submitting code and running it on the website. After quite a bit of googling, I still haven't found any "guides" for this.

Does anyone know of a website(or other sources) that contains some basic guidelines or ground rules for this?

Appreciate all replies.

PS: If anyone wonders about all the programming language tags, I'm planning on supporting at least these languages.

Comment: This looks like a long list of relatively simple steps. Which one is blocking you ?

Comment: for running javascript, html, css, jquery, take a look at how http://www.jsfiddle.net works. For running php take a look at http://writecodeonline.com/php/.

Comment: IMO your question is far too broad. Furthermore I do not really understand the problem. Your application just requires an interpreter for all the languages you want to support...

Comment: You still haven't found any guides because you do not understand what  do you want, if you understand it you will ask google correct question and google answer you.

Comment: In the logic of Dexter's answer, you should also look at http://codepad.org/

Comment: I think this genre of sites is pretty new, so it's unlikely you'll have a baked template to work from. Best option is probably to pick the easiest one (i.e. browser based - js/html/css) and start from there. See http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @dystroy lmao, that was funny. I was trying to show him the interface part, and how it works in action, not the coding technique. Remember that building the interface is also part of the whole infra.

Comment: you can also check out http://w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events. An idea is to send the code to the php back and, which will create a temporary page to then send to an iframe for the javascript html and css. You could then use some php script that may exist to execute the php code on the back end. I think the php is the hardest part since by having your php code execute it it becomes very insecure and the security will probable take some high level code I don't know (but someone on here might.) I can't edit, but I'd add "and how do I secure it" to your question.

Comment: Basically, you need these things: good interface, a syntax checker, a compiler/interpreter for the specific language, and a view, probably an iframe, to display output and/or error/warning messages.

Comment: You will want to be extremely careful doing this. These sites attract a lot of malicious coders.

Comment: @Zéychin And that requires him to implement a malicious code filter/blocker [more like an anti-virus and/or firewall].

Answer (score 1):

Careful -- if you're finding it difficult to break this project down into some smaller, more tactical problems, I'd strongly suggest that you make no attempt whatsoever to actually run anyone else's code on your site.  In terms of creating the site itself, I'd suggest leveraging pre-built components or services where possible -- Wordpress, GitHub, etc.

Once you've got the submissions, you'll want to have a way to run them ***safely***.  For all practical purposes, this means that you should assume that any machine you run someone else's code on might spontaneously burst into flames.  While it's true that some of these languages have features you should be able to use to run code in a "sandbox", you're probably not going to be expert enough in all these languages to be able to properly secure all of them.

It seems that something like Amazon's EC2 might be helpful -- spin up a VM when you need to run a submission, and throw it away when you're done.  They've got some pre-configured images that would probably be well-suited to running this code, and if something gets buggered up because of buggy or malicious code, you don't mind too much because you're just going to throw it away when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a site that already does this, albeit for a particular purpose: scraping data.

https://scraperwiki.com/ - Unlike jsfiddle, **scraperwiki** executes server-side code.  As far as I can gather, they likely sandbox the environment via amazon instances.  Not sure that their code can be entirely audited and sanitized, given the variety of languages and scraping libraries they support.

I think most people are baffled as to how scraperwiki keeps hackers and spammers at bay from misusing their resources. They've been rather mum about it; either they've manually audited every bit of executed code, or hackers/spammers haven't caught onto them yet.  Since the site has a specific function, they probably check data utilization to determine suspicious activity.  ...but, one man's site scraping is another man's harassment and injection by get/post.

My hunch is that they'll never publicly spell out what their security audit process is like.

If you really had to do it, simplest mechanical way of doing this without virtualization is to use a variant of **eval()**.  But, not all languages have that.  Which brings you to option B, which is **virtualization**.  Better people than I can explain how to regiment virtual machines to this effect, and will caution you properly on letting strangers abuse your resources.  Instead, I'll share my PHP experience.

Some years back I've made a project that does code execution on the fly (on a local machine.)  As you type, it takes the code via ajax and executes after each keystroke.  Here's a video of its behavior: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfxrt2pc3pg.

Half a decade and 3 improvement prototypes later, I'm still not sure how I would responsibly lock this down as a common resource.

Answer (score 0):

For Java it is quite simply:

- You're have to create [Servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html), for uploading source code into server (for
  example, via POST request)
- Use Java Compiler API to compile source code to bytecode ( [tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/) )
- Compiled bytecode you're might dynamically load via [ClassLoader](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-indepth.html) and launch it (also you're might configure [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html))
- And don't forget about MVC architecture :)